# Typescript - Interface of string values

Tags: typescript

I have a property which can basically contain 4 possible strings.

At the moment I'm using a simple `|` however I need to reuse those types else where, however how do I create an interface for just those 4 values:

```
selectedState?: "" | "IN_PROGRESS" | "SUCCESS" | "ERROR"
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
interface SelectedStates: "" | "IN_PROGRESS" | "SUCCESS" | "ERROR"
```

and then

```
selectedState?: SelectedStates
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [type alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases):

> Type aliases create a new name for a type. Type aliases are sometimes
>   similar to interfaces, but can name primitives, unions, tuples, and
>   any other types that you’d otherwise have to write by hand.

Like:

```
export type SelectedStates = "" | "IN_PROGRESS" | "SUCCESS" | "ERROR";

// Elsewhere
selectedState?: SelectedStates;
```

Comment: Great, that was it. I just came across it :)